# Dynamically adding a form to a Django formset

Tags: django

I want to dynamically add new forms to a Django formset, so that when the user clicks an "add" button it runs JavaScript that adds a new form (which is part of the formset) to the page.

Comment: I'm just guessing at your use case here, is it something like the "Attach Another File" feature in gmail, where the user is presented with a file upload field and new fields are added to the DOM on the fly as the user clicks to "Attach Another File" plus button?

Comment: This is something I was going to work on soon, so I'll also be interested in any answers.

Comment: I think this is a much better solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353710/how-would-you-make-a-dynamic-formset-in-django Does things clone doesn't: - Add form when no initial forms exists - Handles javascript in the form better, for example django-ckeditor - Keep initial data

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69214880) for django 3.x, using pure JavaScript to add or remove new forms.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

This is how I do it, using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

My template:

```
<h3>My Services</h3>
{{ serviceFormset.management_form }}
{% for form in serviceFormset.forms %}
    <div class='table'>
    <table class='no_error'>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<input type="button" value="Add More" id="add_more">
<script>
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        cloneMore('div.table:last', 'service');
    });
</script>
```

In a javascript file:

```
function cloneMore(selector, type) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var newFor = $(this).attr('for').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        $(this).attr('for', newFor);
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
}
```

What it does:

`cloneMore` accepts `selector` as the first argument, and the `type` of formset as the 2nd one. What the `selector` should do is pass it what it should duplicate. In this case, I pass it `div.table:last` so that jQuery looks for the last table with a class of `table`. The `:last` part of it is important because the `selector` is also used to determine what the new form will be inserted after. More than likely you'd want it at the end of the rest of the forms. The `type` argument is so that we can update the `management_form` field, notably `TOTAL_FORMS`, as well as the actual form fields. If you have a formset full of, say, `Client` models, the management fields will have IDs of `id_clients-TOTAL_FORMS` and `id_clients-INITIAL_FORMS`, while the form fields will be in a format of `id_clients-N-fieldname` with `N` being the form number, starting with `0`. So with the `type` argument the `cloneMore` function looks at how many forms there currently are, and goes through every input and label inside the new form replacing all the field names/ids from something like `id_clients-(N)-name` to `id_clients-(N+1)-name` and so on. After it is finished, it updates the `TOTAL_FORMS` field to reflect the new form and adds it to the end of the set.

This function is particularly helpful to me because the way it is setup it allows me to use it throughout the app when I want to provide more forms in a formset, and doesn't make me need to have a hidden "template" form to duplicate as long as I pass it the formset name and the format in which the forms are laid out.

Comment: In IE, a clone from a cloned element is represented as <undefined> when selecting in JS, why?

Comment: I found that in Django 1.1 you'll need to assign a value to the `prefix` member of the Formset Object. This should the same value as the `type` argument for the `cloneMore` function.

Comment: I modified this to take the selector without :last and used var total = $(selector).length; to get my total because a refresh of the page would remove my formsets but leave the TOTAL increase leading to the wrong number being saved. I then added :last to the selector as needed. Thank for this.

Comment: I have found that this using  $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked'); To clear the input will mess up checkboxes. Setting val('') gives the checkboxes an empty value attribute. And since checkboxes don't use the value attribute this will never be updated - no matter how many times you click it. But it seems that value has higher priority than the "checked" attributed of checkboxes. Which will mean that you will always post non checked checkboxes.

Comment: please paolo can you check my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62252867/inline-formset-only-save-the-last-form/62259041#62259041

Comment: i need to replace this line `var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();` with `var total = $('#id_' + type + '_set-TOTAL_FORMS').val();`. ie added `_set`

Comment: file field didn't cleared on newly added item

Comment: Is this correct solution? newly created formset ids are not correct.

Answer (score 135):

Simplified version of Paolo's answer using [`empty_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#empty-form) as a template.

```
<h3>My Services</h3>
{{ serviceFormset.management_form }}
<div id="form_set">
    {% for form in serviceFormset.forms %}
        <table class='no_error'>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add More" id="add_more">
<div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
    <table class='no_error'>
        {{ serviceFormset.empty_form.as_table }}
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how can i deal this in the view? when i use `CompetitorFormSet = modelformset_factory(ProjectCompetitor, formset=CompetitorFormSets)` 
`ctx['competitor_form_set'] = CompetitorFormSet(request.POST)`
i Only get one form, in in clean method. can you please explain how to deal this in views?

Comment: Brilliant – thank you. Makes excellent use of the available Django helpers (like `empty_form`), which I appreciate.

Comment: @BigglesZX - I have adapted the solution and the new rows of empty forms are getting generated. However the select boxes are generating a list of FK (available) choices, instead of drop downs which are otherwise being generated for the original set of forms. Has any issue of this nature been reported?

Comment: @Dave could you update answer for later versions i.e 3.x ? it's simple and clear but it's not working for me

Comment: @PoulaAdel What isn't working? I just tried this on Django 3.0.5 and it still works for me. Surprising after 8 years, but I guess Django and jQuery have good backward compatibility with older code.

Answer (score 17):

Paolo's suggestion works beautifully with one caveat - the browser's back/forward buttons.

The dynamic elements created with Paolo's script will not be rendered if the user returns to the formset using the back/forward button. An issue that may be a deal breaker for some.

Example:

1) User adds two new forms to the formset using the "add-more" button

2) User populates the forms and submits the formset

3) User clicks the back button in the browser

4) Formset is now reduced to the original form, all dynamically added forms are not there

This is not a defect with Paolo's script at all; but a fact of life with dom manipulation and browser's cache.

I suppose one could store the values of the form in the session and have some ajax magic when the formset loads to create the elements again and reload the values from the session; but depending on how anal you want to be about the same user and multiple instances of the form this may become very complicated.

Anyone has a good suggestion for dealing with this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you redirect after successful submission, the back button isn't a problem.  If you fill the forms from the DB on the next visit, all the forms appear initially.  If you fail the forms due to invalid input, all of them should be there on the redisplay with errors.  Unless I'm not understanding your statements....  That post submission redirect is really important in a good working app, one that lots of coders just don't get based on the number of poorly behaving apps I run into on the web.

Comment: Also, add a warning before submission/leaving

Answer (score 11):

Simulate and imitate:

- Create a formset which corresponds to the situation **before** clicking the "add" button.
- Load the page, view the source and take a note of all `<input>` fields.
- Modify the formset to correspond to the situation **after** clicking the "add" button (change the number of extra fields).
- Load the page, view the source and take a note of how the `<input>` fields changed.
- Create some JavaScript which modifies the DOM in a suitable way to move it from the **before** state to the **after** state.
- Attach that JavaScript to the "add" button.

While I do know formsets use special hidden `<input>` fields and know approximately what the script must do, I don't recall the details off the top of my head. What I described above is what I would do in your situation.

Answer (score 7):

For the coders out there who are hunting resources to understand the above solutions a little better:

[Django Dynamic Formsets](http://schinckel.net/2017/02/05/django-dynamic-formsets/)

After reading the above link, the Django documentation and previous solutions should make a lot more sense.

[Django Formset Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/)

As a quick summary of what I was getting confused by: The Management Form contains an overview of the forms within. You must keep that information accurate in order for Django to be aware of the forms you add. (Community, please give me suggestions if some of my wording is off here. Im new to Django.)

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to create a formset with every possible form, but initially set the unrequired forms to hidden - ie, `display: none;`.  When it's necessary to display a form, set it's css display to `block` or whatever is appropriate.

Without know more details of what your "Ajax" is doing, it's hard to give a more detailed response.

Answer (score 4):

Another cloneMore version, which allows for selective sanitization of fields. Use it when you need to prevent several fields from being erased.

```
$('table tr.add-row a').click(function() {
    toSanitize = new Array('id', 'product', 'price', 'type', 'valid_from', 'valid_until');
    cloneMore('div.formtable table tr.form-row:last', 'form', toSanitize);
});

function cloneMore(selector, type, sanitize) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
        var namePure = $(this).attr('name').replace(type + '-' + (total-1) + '-', '');
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).removeAttr('checked');

        if ($.inArray(namePure, sanitize) != -1) {
            $(this).val('');
        }

    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var newFor = $(this).attr('for').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        $(this).attr('for', newFor);
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
}
```

Comment: can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285767/how-to-make-django-inlineformset-template , i've tried alot  but didnt get an answer ! i much appreciate you

Answer (score 3):

Because all answers above use jQuery and make some things a bit complex I wrote following script:

```
function $(selector, element) {
    if (!element) {
        element = document
    }
    return element.querySelector(selector)
}

function $$(selector, element) {
    if (!element) {
        element = document
    }
    return element.querySelectorAll(selector)
}

function hasReachedMaxNum(type, form) {
    var total = parseInt(form.elements[type + "-TOTAL_FORMS"].value);
    var max = parseInt(form.elements[type + "-MAX_NUM_FORMS"].value);
    return total >= max
}

function cloneMore(element, type, form) {
    var totalElement = form.elements[type + "-TOTAL_FORMS"];
    total = parseInt(totalElement.value);
    newElement = element.cloneNode(true);
    for (var input of $$("input", newElement)) {
        input.name = input.name.replace("-" + (total - 1) + "-", "-" + total + "-");
        input.value = null
    }
    total++;
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element.nextSibling);
    totalElement.value = total;
    return newElement
}
var addChoiceButton = $("#add-choice");
addChoiceButton.onclick = function() {
    var choices = $("#choices");
    var createForm = $("#create");
    cloneMore(choices.lastElementChild, "choice_set", createForm);
    if (hasReachedMaxNum("choice_set", createForm)) {
        this.disabled = true
    }
};
```

First you should set [auto_id](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.auto_id) to false and so disable the duplication of id and name. Because the input names have to be unique in there form, all identification is done with them and not with id's.
You also have to replace the `form`, `type` and the container of the formset. (In the example above `choices`)

Answer (score 2):

There is a small issue with the cloneMore function. Since it's also cleaning the value of the django auto-generated hidden fields, it causes django to complain if you try to save a formset with more than one empty form.

Here is a fix:

```
function cloneMore(selector, type) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;

        if ($(this).attr('type') != 'hidden') {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).removeAttr('checked');
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var newFor = $(this).attr('for').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        $(this).attr('for', newFor);
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
}
```

Comment: Sorry @art_cs, I haven't worked with Django in several years. Please study the answers to this question carefully, and use the debugger in your browser's developer tools, I'm sure it's fairly easy to solve. I'd also look around for a pre-packaged solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yea I'd also recommend just rendering them out in the html if you have a finite number of entries. (If you don't you'll have to user another method).

You can hide them like this:

```
{% for form in spokenLanguageFormset %}
    <fieldset class="languages-{{forloop.counter0 }} {% if spokenLanguageFormset.initial_forms|length < forloop.counter and forloop.counter != 1 %}hidden-form{% endif %}">
```

Then the js is really simple:

```
addItem: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var maxForms = parseInt($(this).closest("fieldset").find("[name*='MAX_NUM_FORMS']").val(), 10);
    var initialForms = parseInt($(this).closest("fieldset").find("[name*='INITIAL_FORMS']").val(), 10);
    // check if we can add
    if (initialForms < maxForms) {
        $(this).closest("fieldset").find("fieldset:hidden").first().show();
        if ($(this).closest("fieldset").find("fieldset:visible").length == maxForms ){
            // here I'm just hiding my 'add' link
            $(this).closest(".control-group").hide();
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [django-dynamic-formsets](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) for everyone who is just looking for a solution that works out of the box.

It replaced all the code I derived from the solutions proposed and gives some additional functionality, such as deleting forms or stylizing related buttons.