# jQuery cloning html, update the DOM?

Tags: html, jquery, django, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I need help of Javascript / jQuery experts to solve the next problem:

---- 1. [this Javascript](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) alerts the id of a selected option in a select html tag:

```
$(function(){
    $("#id_productos_list").change(
    function(){
        var op = $(this).selectedValues()
        alert(op);
     }
     );
});
```

----2. [this Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax) clone html code:

```
function cloneMore(selector, type) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone();
    var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    
    newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var newFor = $(this).attr('for').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        $(this).attr('for', newFor);
    });

    total++;
    $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);
}
```

---- this is a part of the HTML code that JS is cloning, and it works with no problems

```
            <select id="id_productos_list" name="productos_list" >
              <option value="1">One</option>
              <option value="2">Two</option>
            </select>
```

BUT just the Javascript #1 works with the initial html code (original for clone). the cloned others doesn't alert selected options.  I've tested with different id's attrs for each cloned select tags, without results.

What am I missing? Firebug display the cloned html DOM nice :S Do I have to update DOM after cloning to make `$("#id productos list").change(...)` works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery `$("#...")` syntax will return the first matched element by exact id.  If you are cloning elements but not differentiating them by their id, this code will not work as you expect it to.

You can compare the differences between the following two expressions:

```
alert($("#id_productos_list").size());
```

...and

```
alert($("[id='#id_productos_list']").size());
```

The first expression will return either zero or one depending on the presence of an element with id "id_productos_list" in your page.  The first element in declared order wins.

The second expression will return zero or one or more depending on the the set of all elements with id "id_productos_list" in your page.

Also important to note is that it doesn't appear that the event handlers are copied over as part of the `clone()` operation.  You may need to reassign these handlers to the new elements.

```
var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
```

Comment: I did a experiment, the original option tag is <select id="asdfasdf" > and the cloned option tag is <select id="id_productos_list" > and jQuery selector is: $("#id_productos_list").change(...). differents id's ok?, but no, does not alert nothing.

Comment: @panchicore: I don't believe the change handler is being cloned to the new elements.  You might have to explicitly add it.

Comment: the winner hint: "You may need to reassign these handlers to the new elements." the solution was simple as adding true to clone method: var newElement = $(selector).clone(true); Thank you David Andres. +9999

Comment: @panchicore: thanks, I got you the gist of it but I feel jgeewax got you the full course a bit sooner.  So, if you have to give credit...

Comment: @David Andres: embarasing situation, but I spend goggle-research thanks to your hint and found it quickly in the jquery API docs. you have the last word ..... say what?

Comment: @panchicore: whichever answer led you to your solution is what gets the vote.  The point to focus on is that you got something out of all of this...

Comment: @panchicore: and there's really no reason to be embarrassed...we all use search engines all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `.clone(true)` which clones all the handlers attached? It's described at the bottom of the [Clone documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Clone).