# Django dynamically added forms - '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm currently creating a site in Django which allows a user to enter in the details of a recipe they want to create and save it. This means the user needs to be able to dynamically add formset fields for things like ingredients and the steps of the recipe.

I have implemented a way to dynamically add these fields using Javascript, but currently it only works with can_delete_extra and can_delete in the formset set to False, which I need to change because a) I don't want a delete checkbox to display on the formset forms when a recipe is being created (I have looked in to hiding this with no luck) and b) the user needs to be able to delete fields they don't want when they edit a recipe later on.

The error message I'm being displayed is: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int', occurring in: Desktop\recipe_site\recipe_env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py, line 416, in add_fields.

The following is my code. The Javascript is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353710/how-would-you-make-a-dynamic-formset-in-django).

**create_recipe.html**

```
<h2>Ingredients</h2>

        {{ iformset.management_form }}
        <div id=ingredientform>
            {% for i_form in iformset %}
            <div class = ingredientinfo>
                {{ i_form.as_p }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <input type="button" value="Add More" id="add_more_ingredients">
        
        <script>
            let ingFormCount = {{ iformset.total_form_count }}
            let emptyIngForm = '{{ iformset.empty_form.as_p|escapejs }}'
        </script>

        <script src="{% static 'recipes/add_more_ingredients.js' %}"></script>
```

**add_more_ingredients.js**

```
let addIngButton = document.querySelector("#add_more_ingredients")

addIngButton.addEventListener('click', addIngForm)


function addIngForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    ingFormCount++
    
    // Update the management form to use the correct value of TOTAL_FORMS
    // to allow extra forms to be saved. 
    let totalForms = document.getElementById("id_ingredients-TOTAL_FORMS")
    totalForms.setAttribute('value', ingFormCount+1)
    let ingredientForm = document.querySelector("#ingredientform")
    let ingContainer = document.createElement('div');
    ingContainer.classList.add('ingredientinfo');
    ingContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", emptyIngForm.replace(/__prefix__/g, ingFormCount))
    ingredientForm.appendChild(ingContainer)
```

**models.py**

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    recipe = models.ForeignKey(
        RecipeCard, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ingredients")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient_name
```

**forms.py**

```
class IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        exclude = ['recipe',]

IngredientFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    RecipeCard, 
    Ingredient, 
    form = IngredientForm, 
    can_delete_extra = False, 
    can_delete = True, 
    extra=2,
    max_num=15)
```

It looks like the following function from the Django formset source code is where the issue lies:

```
def add_fields(self, form, index):
        """A hook for adding extra fields on to each form instance."""
        if self.can_order:
            # Only pre-fill the ordering field for initial forms.
            if index is not None and index < self.initial_form_count():
```

From what I can tell (I'm not very experienced), the error is being generated because in my code,  `index` above is None. I took a look at the rest of the formset source code and also found this, which I thought could be relevant since in my template `<script>` tag I'm generating an empty form:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
        """
        Return additional keyword arguments for each individual formset form.

        index will be None if the form being constructed is a new empty
        form.
        """
        return self.form_kwargs.copy()
```

Help would be appreciated as to how to go about solving this/ if this is solvable by modifying my code/ overriding Django in some way - or whether you think there could be a better method to implement dynamic form addition in Django. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can give index a default value like

```
def add_fields(self, form, index=7):
```

and choose your default value according to what you want to happen if the value is not given.

Comment: Would have to edit the Django source code (formsets.py) for this, which I have been led to believe is a bad idea unfortunately.