# Django: How to add a form to bounded formset in backend?

Tags: django, django-forms

Basically, what I'd like to do is take a formset that has been bounded to request.POST, add a blank form to it, and return the new formset.

```
class MyView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        MyFormSet = formset_factory(MyForm)
        posted_formset = MyFormSet(request.POST)

        # Append a blank form to posted_formset here
        return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'formset': posted_formset})
```

Is there any clean way to do this in Django 1.6? Right now I've got a workaround that involves creating a new formset with `initial` set to the data bound in `posted_formset`, but it's kind of clunky, and I feel like there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: `extra=1` is not enough for you?

Comment: @danihp No, extra=1 just gives me the bound formset with no extra form, it's the default value for the parameter in formset_factory anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like there's no clean way to do this, as after a formset is bound to a QueryDict, the extra parameter passed to `formset_factory` becomes irrelevant. Here's how I'm doing it in my view right now:

```
class MyView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        MyFormSet = formset_factory(MyForm)
        posted_formset = MyFormSet(request.POST)

        initial = []
        for form in posted_formset:
            data = {}
            for field in form.fields:
                data[field] = form[field].value()
            initial.append(data)

        formset = AuthorFormSet(initial=initial)
        return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Basically, I bind a formset to request.POST, then iterate through it and grab the field values and put them into an array of dicts, `initial`, which I pass in when I make a new formset (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset)) that will have an extra blank form at the end because it's not bound.

This should work with any form and formset. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a possible duplicate of this question: [Django: How to add an extra form to a formset after it has been constructed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950627/django-how-to-add-an-extra-form-to-a-formset-after-it-has-been-constructed#4964369)

Otherwise have a look at the extra parameter for the factory function. You get more information about formsets in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)