# Simple dynamic form in Django controlled by the user

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

I want to make a simple accounting application and I have a model with 3 fields:

- account_symbol
- account_debit
- account_credit

And I want to make a form for the user to enter the accounts for the balance, after entering the first set (of 3 fields) the form (after the user press a button) should reveal another set and so on.

After all the accounts should be entered, the user should submit the form to the database.

I read the b-list.org approach and I don't think is what I need and the formsets docs but what I want is the user to control the length of the form by adding additional sets of 3 fields.

Please point me to an approach for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formset is exactly what you need here. You just need to use JavaScript to dynamically show new formsets to user (like in admin app). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax)'s nice example of doing this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll have to dive in.