# Best practice to render dynamic flask WTForm FieldList (with nesting)

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2, wtforms

This has been asked a lot but no clear answer so far.

Is there an "official" way or an extension to render WTForm `FieldList` **with the ability to add/remove fields with buttons**?

I find it weird that no one has normalized that so far. All the answers I found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000595/working-with-wtforms-fieldlist), [here](https://gist.github.com/kageurufu/6813878) or [here](https://www.rmedgar.com/blog/dynamic-fields-flask-wtf)) are hand-written JavaScript that would break if:

1. There is 0 field (a "template" is needed to clone the items)
2. `FieldList`/`FormField` get nested

I did write a solution as well but as soon as I tried to make it generic (to handle nesting and applicable to multiple forms), it becomes almost impossible to handle. I'm trying to find a generic solution that would work on all my forms to avoid having to maintain them all "field by field", any ideas?

Example of form:

```
- field1 = StringField
- field2 = FieldList
    - field2_1 = StringField
- field3 = FieldList
    - field3_1 = FormField
        - field3_1_1 = StringField
        - field3_1_2 = FieldList
            - field3_1_2_1 = StringField
    - field2_2 = StringField
- field2_2 = StringField
```

**Bonus question:** A solution that is Boostrap4 friendly?

Comment: It's not really a very satisfying answer, but as someone with a fair amount of flask-wtf experience, I would say there isn't a canonical or even very good way of doing this kind of dynamic stuff in WTForms.

Comment: Thanks, I feel the reason for that is that if you need dynamic nested lists of variable length that means the design is bad in the first place. That still seems a kind of "basic" need.