# Dynamically adding a formset to a form in Django with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-forms

How can I go about implementing the following use case with AJAX? I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax) which was the closest I could find to my use case but I'm still unsure on how to get started.

**Use Case**

I enter a quantity number, say '3', into an input text field for a ticket item. After entering this value, 3 formsets appear below with an email field.

Conceptually, I'm thinking, on the change of the input value, load the django formset variable like

```
    {% for form in formset %}
    {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
```

within the javascript onChange function but I'm not sure how to actually do this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar use case where a formset can be either rendered by a standard http response or by a Ajax load.

My DRY solution is :

### standard http response (the whole page)

The view instanciate the formset, render the template, but in it I have an `{% include "path/to/formset-snippet.html %}` tag (surrounded by a *with* tag for reusability with the following).

### AJAX response

I make a Ajax call to render a html fragment in the DOM node (say a ). In **JQuery** this is something like that :

```
$("#my_container").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
      if (status == "error") {
        $(this).html("Sorry but there was an error: " + 
                     xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText +
                     '<div style="height:300px; overflow:scroll;">' + 
                     response + "</div>");
      }
});
```

The view instanciate the same formset and render *formset-snippet.html*. Here an exemple of *MyModel* having *images* associated with :

```
@login_required
def images_formset(request, object_id):
    instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=object_id)
    prefix = request.GET.get('form_prefix', None)
    formset = ImageMyModelFormSet(instance=instance, prefix=prefix)
    return render_to_response('my_app/images_my_model_form_snippet.html', {
                              'images_my_model_formset': formset,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Hope it can helps.