# Binding autocomplete to a dynamically added form field

Tags: jquery, dynamic, input, autocomplete

I'm trying to bind the jQuery UI autocomplete widget to a dynamically added input field. I've read some of the posts here, but none seem to help.

The code I'm using comes from [Dynamically adding a form to a Django formset with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax) and I've slightly modified it to bind the autocomplete.

However, the bind doesn't seem to be working. Whenever I type in the newly added field, the autocomplete box doesn't show. The code I am using follows:

```
function cloneMore(selector, type,field) {
    var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
    var total = $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        var id = 'id_' + name;

        if ($(this).attr('type') != 'hidden') {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).removeAttr('checked');
    });
    newElement.find('label').each(function() {
        var newFor = $(this).attr('for').replace('-' + (total-1) + '-','-' + total + '-');
        $(this).attr('for', newFor);
    });
    total++;
    $('#id_' + type + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
    $(selector).after(newElement);

    /* create the selector string and bind autocomplete */
    var select_string = "#id_"+type+"-"+(total-1)+"-"+field;
    $( select_string).autocomplete({
        source: asset_universe_codes,
    });

}
```

I have checked that the autocomplete source is accessible within the function, so I'm at a loss.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Have you tried .on() and delegate()?

Comment: I haven't, no. I'm relatively new to jQuery, so I wasn't aware of those methods. Delegate looks like it might be promising, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that newElement hasn't been appended to the DOM, if this is the case then appending it (prior to calling autocomplete) should resolve your issue.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was under the impression that 'after' did that for me. I'll look up how to append and give that a go, thanks.

Comment: Would it be possible to get an example of this, please? I struggled to find an answer.