# django crispy-forms inline forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to adopt crispy-forms and bootstrap and use as much of their functionality as possible instead of inventing something over and over again.

Is there a way to have inline forms functionality with crispy-forms/bootstrap like django-admin forms have?

Here is an example:

```
class NewProjectForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_(u'Название проекта'), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'input-block-level'}))
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Group.objects.all(), label=_(u'Группа проектов'), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'input-block-level'}))
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_(u'Описание проекта'), widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'input-block-level'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('name','description','group')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'horizontal-form'
        self.helper.form_action = 'submit_new_project'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('name', css_class='input-block-level'),
            Field('group', css_class='input-block-level'),
            Field('description',css_class='input-block-level'),
        )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit',_(u'Создать проект')))
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('cancel',_(u'Я передумал')))
        super(NewProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

it will display a decent form:

[image: example of single form rendered with crispy-forms]

How do I go about adding a form that basically represents this model:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_(u'Название'))
    url = models.URLField(blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=_(u'Ссылка'))
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
```

So there will be a project and name/url links and way to add many, like same thing is done in django-admin where you are able to add extra 'rows' with data related to your main model. On the sreenshot below you are able to fill out data for 'Question' object and below that you are able to add data for QuestionOption objects -you are able to click the '+' icon to add as many QuestionOptions as you want.

I'm not looking for a way to get the forms auto-generated from models (that's nice but not the most important) - is there a way to construct a form that will let you add 'rows' of data like django-admin does?

[image: screenshot of django-admin]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inline forms you refer to, are known in Django as Formsets. If you want to know more about formsets, you can find them in [the Django forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/).

Crispy supports rendering inline formsets, as described in [the section 'Rendering Formsets'](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/tags.html#rendering-formsets)

Please note that formsets by default show 3 extra inline forms, allowing you to add three more objects. After saving, you again get three extra inline formsets to add even more.

If you want an 'add more' button like in the Django Admin, you will need to use some Javascript to dynamically add those rows.

Comment: This question goes into more detail about dynamic 'add more' buttons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

If using class based views, you can use [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views).