# Click function in Django form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have no idea how can I solve my problem. I have Django template with two models. I put these models in inlineformset_factory.

**Example**

```
DhcpConfigFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Dhcp, IPRange, extra=1)
```

and I displayed this form in template like this pictures

[form http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/601592_10151469446139596_1335258068_n.jpg](http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/601592_10151469446139596_1335258068_n.jpg)

I want implement event, when I click on plus stick (marked field on pictures), show one more row (ip initial field, ip final field and delete check box).

**I tried to do it on this way :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".plusthick-left").click( function() {
          var tr= $(".sort-table").find("tbody tr:last").length;
               $(".sort-table").find("tbody tr:last").after($(".sort- table").find("tbody tr:last").clone())
      });
```

but I have problem, because I just made copy of last row and took same attributes values?

**My question is :** How can I make new row, and set all attributes with values of last row increased by one.

**For example:**

```
<input type="text" id="id_ip_initial_0_ip_range">
```

This is field that generated form in template, and I want make field with id value like this:

```
<input type="text" id="id_ip_initial_1_ip_range">
```

How can I do it? :)

Comment: Something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax)?

Comment: tnx.. I sloved my problem. It is very helpfull.