# Add OneToMany relation model instances from parent model instance Django Form

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-forms

I have a Person model:

```
    class Person(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And then a Car model:

```
    class Car(models.Model):
        plate = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

And then a certain CarAttribute model:

```
    class CarAttribute(models.Model):
        whatever = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
        car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

Person has a relation 1 to many to Car. Car has a relation 1 to many to Car attributre.

Is there a way in Django for adding the Car (and eventually its relative CarAttributes) in the Form to be used when adding a new Person? One person may have more than one car, and one car can multiple attributes.

Any hints on how to approach this solution with Django? Or complementary tool?

Comment: You need to use fomsets. Check links to the nested formsets implementation  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894629/django-nested-inline-formsets

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646323/how-to-make-master-detail-model-screen-in-django