# How django inlineformset works?

Tags: django, django-forms

How Django's inlineformset work? What is the concept behind the hidden id field?

I've three models

```
class QuestionSet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Question(models.Model):
    question_set = models.ForeignKey(QuestionSet)
    question = models.TextField(blank=False)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I would like to create a page with form, where there is one field for QuestionSet, multiple Question fields and each question has field for many answer fields. The questions and answers initial extra can be 4 but should be extendable via javascript. Say a + button to add one more option to a question. And another + button to add one more option to add a new question with default 4 answer fields.

I've read and understood [Dynamically adding a form to a Django formset with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax). I need the same feature for nested inline formset.

[image: Following is a prototype]