# Using ajax with django in multiple formset

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I tried to make dynamically add multiple forms using formset in django. I used ajax to send the request for add the form by the client. I made an add_another button to add the formset. Whenever the user clicks this button an increment to count is made and the request is send through ajax to the server(to the views of my django).My code looks as follows:

**views.py**

```
def trial_balance(request):
    formcount = 1
    if request.is_ajax():   
        count = request.POST.get('mycount', formcount)              
        formcount = count
    myformset = formset_factory(DateRangeForm,extra=formcount)
    if request.method == "POST":
        f = myformset()
        if f.is_valid():  
    else:
        f = myformset()
    args['formcount'] = formcount
    args['myformset'] = f
    return render(request, 'trial_balance.html', args)
```

**trial_balance.html**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#add_another").click(function(){
                count = {{ formcount }};
                count++;
                alert(count);       
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/report/trial-balance",
                    data: { 'mycount' : count}
                }).done(function() {
                    alert("DONE");
                    }).fail(function() {
                    alert("FAIL");
                    });
                 });

        });
    </script>
    <div>
    <form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ myformset.as_p }}
        <button id="add_another">add another</button>
        <input  type = "submit"  value = "See Results" id = "daterangeresult">

    </form>
```

I always get fail alert and when printing the value of formcount from views.py I always get the value 1 even though the button is clicked.

Comment: Is this `if f.is_valid():` a typo just below `f = myformset()`? If it is, that's the problem, the server is returning a 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

look at [dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax) or [Dynamically adding forms to a formset with jQuery in Django](https://gist.github.com/jteso/2130643) this might help you