# "Add another form" button in template (like django admin)

Tags: python, django

How can I make an "Add another ____" button for a rendered formset?

I've noticed people go about this using jQuery ([Dynamically adding a form to a Django formset with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax))

The django polls tutorial does not really explain how the "Add another Choice" link is generated in the admin.
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/)

How can I reuse that same functionality in my templates, views & forms?

Here is some of my code.

**forms.py**

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # The last 15 years.
    thisYear = int(time.strftime("%Y"))
    farAway = thisYear-15
    years = []
    for y in range(farAway,thisYear):
        years.append(str(y))

    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=tuple(years)))
    class Meta:
        model = Student
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = ''

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(StudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**add-students.html**

```
<h2>Add Students</h2>
    {% for f in StudentFormSet %}
        {% crispy f %}
    {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
def addStudents(request):
    StudentFormSet = formset_factory(StudentForm, can_delete=True, extra=3)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = StudentFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            saved = formset.save(commit=False)
            saved.save()
            messages.success(request, "Submitted! Thank you.")
    else:
        formset = StudentFormSet()
    return render_to_response('add-students.html', 
                                locals(),
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: That is exactly correct.. read the post you linked. You can generate an empty formset via {{ formset.empty_form }} which has convenient placeholders for javascript to replace. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#empty-form