# Loading dynamic forms in django select option

Tags: python, django

I have a model.py with some common fields

Class Top(models.Model):

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
.
.
<more fields here>
.
.
SELECT_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'First'),
    ('2', 'Second'),
     .
     .
)
status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SELECT_CHOICES)
```

what I am trying to achieve is:

- display SELECT_CHOICES as dropdown select options of form
- when the user/admin selects different options it appends different form fields at the bottom
- I want to do it both on frontend and backend.

Example output:

```
Title = ......

<other Fields>

Selected = First

textField = .........



Title = ......

<other Fields>

Selected = Second

RadioButton = Option1 Option2
```

Can someone please guide me how can I do this in Django?

Comment: you'll need some JS to do that, and use a `positivesmallintegerfield` instead of a CharField

Comment: Found answer to the similar query here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/669982/3120889