# Django: Create form for ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I currently have a django project going and I am customizing my django-usernea installation by adding custom profile fields. I would like the user to add their skills/interests as part of their profile, so I set up my models.py like the following:

```
class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,  
                        verbose_name=_('user'),related_name='my_profile')
    GENDER = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('U', 'Prefer Not To Say'),
    )
    #favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),max_length=5) 
    #firstname = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    #lastname = models.CharField(max_length=66)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=190, blank=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, choices = GENDER)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    #skills = models.ManyToManyField('Skills', blank=True)
    #Interests = models.ManyToManyField('Interests', blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)


class Skills(models.Model):
    skillName = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    MyProfile = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.skillName

class Interests(models.Model):
    interestName = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
    MyProfile = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
    def __str__(self):
        return interestName
```

However, how can I create a form so the user can actually enter their skills and interests? I read about inline model forms, but isn't that only for the admin side?

Comment: No, why would they only be for the admin? They are fully documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically adding a form to a Django formset with Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax)