# Better ways to handle dynamically generated forms in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form that allow users to log their activities. To make it simple, let's say I only have two fields that I want a user to fill out.

- Time
- Action

During a day, a user can fill out multiple time + action pairs. I used javascript on the front end to allow users to add these pairs as they wish.

Thus, I do not know how many pairs there will be beforehand. And thus, I cannot create a predefined ModelForm for it.

To deal with this issue, I labeled each Time and Action field with a unique name. So when I receive a POST request, I geta list like this inside the request.POST dictionary:

- time_1: 9:50
- action_1: wakeup
- time_2: 11:00
- aciton_2: workout
- ...

Then, I subtract each pair out of the dictionary and put them into a ModelForm for validation and save to the database.

```
class TimeActionModel(Model):
    time = DateField()
    action = CharField(max_length=100)

class TimeActionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TimeActionModel

class TimeActionView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self._subtract_and_save(request)

    def _subtract_and_save(request):
        #loop through the request.POST dictionary
            #pull out each pair
            #stuff each one into a ModelForm object
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
```

Here is my quesiton:

- Does this approach look right to you?
- What's the 'Django way' of dealing with such situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a concept in Django called [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/):

> A formset is a layer of abstraction to work with multiple forms on the same page. It can be best compared to a data grid.

The Django way would be to use [Model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets):

> Like regular formsets, Django provides a couple of enhanced formset classes that make it easy to work with Django models.

Therefore you could create a model formset for your `TimeActionModel` as such:

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

TimeActionFormset = modelformset_factory(TimeActionModel)
```

You can read more on that in the documentation. It has extensive use cases and examples to cover your case.

UPDATE: The `extras` parameter of the formset is not quite important. You can easily manipulate the number of extra forms in your formset [with a bit of javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097617/940098). There are also contrib packages for that such as [django-dynamic-formset](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset).

UPDATE2: The name of the fields depends on the `prefix` used too, which I recommend it in case of many different forms/formsets in a single page, but you can easily deduce it looking at a default form that Django renders.

Also please take not not to forget in your template to include `{{ my_formset.management_form }}` and `{{ my_formsets_form.id }}`!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. While reading the formset documentation, it states `formset_factory(ArticleForm, extra=2)` which means you have to define how many sets there will be displayed on the rendered page. But for my situation, I do not know how many TimeAction pairs there will be. Thus, I have no idea what number of extra I should set it to.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean. It looks like I need to use javascript to increment the hidden 'form-TOTAL_FORMS' everytime a new form is added. Also, with a newly added form, I need to make sure each input field has a name in the 'form-set_number-field_name' format. Am I right?

Comment: Welcome! Again updated answer and added link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8097617/940098