# Django: dynamic formset with Jquery only save first formset instance

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-forms

So I have set up the following codes for sample from followed by inline formset of its foreign key, sample detail. I also added some dynamic feature to it so that you could add more rows for the formset via Jquery. I got the Jquery section from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax](http://OS%20post). I tried both implementation but it appears to have the same result. I am wondering if I did something wrong in the view.

views.py

```
def project_detail (request, project_id):
     project = Project.objects.get(id = project_id)
     sample_form = SampleForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance = project)
     SampleInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Sample, SampleDetail, form=SampleDetailForm, extra=1, can_delete = False)
     formset = SampleInlineFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, prefix="nested")
     if request.method == "POST":

        if 'sampleform' in request.POST:
            if sample_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
                 sample_temp = sample_form.save()
                 sample = Sample.objects.get(pk = sample_temp.pk)
                 objects = formset.save(commit=False)
                 for object in objects:
                       object.sample = sample
                       object.save()

                 messages.success(request, "Sucessfully Created New Sample Log" )
                 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projstatus:project_detail', args=(project_id,)))           
     context = {'project' : project, "sample_form":sample_form, 'formset' : formset}
     return render(request, 'projstatus/detail.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
             {% crispy sample_form %}

             <div id="form_set">
                 {{ formset.management_form }}
                 {% for form in formset.forms %}
                     <table class='no_error'>

                         {{ form.as_table }}
                     </table>
                 {% endfor %}
             </div>
             <input type="button" value="Add More" id="add_more">

             <div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
                 <table class='no_error'>
                     {{ formset.empty_form.as_table }}

                 </table>
             </div>
             <script>
                 $('#add_more').click(function() {
                     var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
                     $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
                     $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
                 });
             </script>


              <button type='submit' class='save btn btn-default' name = 'sampleform'>Save</button>      

             </form>
```

However, I have this problem that only the first formset instance is ever saved. no matter how many I put in dynamically. Could someone please help me?

Edit:

The look of the form
[image]

POST data when using Jquery to add one more instance (2 instances in total)
[image]

POST data when not using Jquery, setting extra = 2. (2 instances in total)
[image]

Comment: The problem could be in your `#add_more` click handler. Compare the values of `request.POST` with and without Javascript (adjust `extra` in the view instead of clicking 'add more'), and make sure you are submitting the exact same data.

Comment: @Alasdair Hi thanks for the comments. I updated with POST data. Seems that it might be the "undefined"  thing in Jquery case that is causing the problem

Comment: Your jQuery post data is missing `nested-1-id`, `nested-1-location` and so on.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks! I still failed to see which part did I make mistake....  Anyway thanks so much

Comment: You may want to draw inspiration from how `django.contrib.admin` handles dynamically adding inline formset forms in [inlines.js](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b63d0c54b05ede2589e2b720eb0c102c02891962/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/inlines.js).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is with your javascript. It seems you took that snippet from another example that's floating around.

`var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();`

For this to work, there needs to be an element with `id` of `id_form-TOTAL_FORMS`.

But I think your form will probably have this input with an id of something like `id_nested-TOTAL_FORMS` or something similar. As a result, I don't think your javascript is actually updating the Formset's management form data.

You should inspect your html on the page and see what the `id` of this input is. Also, use the javascript console to see what your JS code is really doing.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried to change #id_form-TOTAL_FORMS to #id_nested-TOTAL_FORMS and it works!

Answer (score 1):

As with the previous answer, the `nested-TOTAL_FORMS` field value needs updating with the number of rows each time you add one. You're currently updating a field `form-TOTAL_FORMS` which doesn't exist.

Try updating the js from `#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS` to `#id_nested-TOTAL_FORMS`

There may also be a way to get the field ID as a template variable but that escapes me at the moment.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried to change #id_form-TOTAL_FORMS to #id_nested-TOTAL_FORMS and it works!