# Dynamically add inline formsets in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I have a form for collecting work experience of an employee. Currently I can add only one experience. I want that if I press a '+' icon or button, same form will be generated under the default form. I dont want to reload page rather I want to do it in a page.

models.py:

```
class WorkExperience(models.Model):
    """
    Stores employee previous work experiences
    """
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', related_name='we_employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    previous_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    job_designation = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    from_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    to_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class WorkExperienceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Creates a form for saving employee work experiences
    """
    class Meta:

        model = WorkExperience
        fields = [
            'previous_company_name',
            'job_designation',
            'from_date',
            'to_date',
            'job_description',
        ]
        widgets = {
                'from_date': DatePickerInput(),
                'to_date': DatePickerInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is my form. I want to add a '+' icon. Everytime user presses the icon, same fields will be generated alongside the default form.
[image]

Comment: You can take a look at this [post](https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically adding a form to a Django formset with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax)

Comment: @pmcarpan- I am not sure. I need to implement