# Add forms to a Django formset dynamically using htmx?

Tags: javascript, django, htmx

There are several writeups on how to use javascript to add forms dynamically to a Django formset.  For example [this](https://www.brennantymrak.com/articles/django-dynamic-formsets-javascript.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset).

I just learned about [htmx](https://htmx.org/).

How can I add forms dynamically to a Django formset using htmx instead of hand-coded javascript?  I thought maybe I could use [click-to-load](https://htmx.org/examples/click-to-load/), but it seems odd to call back to the server to get an empty row.  Maybe this just isn't an htmx thing.

Answer (score 2):

With HTMX, instead of the complication of formsets, you can dynamically add forms, and swap in the resulting model instance on submit.

This [example todo app](https://github.com/OmenApps/django-htmx-todo-list) provides a demonstration of the approach. It allows you to add additional items by appending a form, and upon submitting successfully, swaps in the model instance resulting from that form submission. The end result is much like using formsets.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question here: [The right way to dynamically add Django formset instances and POST usign HTMX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757197/the-right-way-to-dynamically-add-django-formset-instances-and-post-usign-htmx/74924295#74924295)

**Here's the summary of my approach:**

1. Create a view function to bring in your new formset via an `hx-get`.
2. In that view function, build the html of your new formset by starting with
   `YourFormset.empty_form` to get the basic html, and then replace the default `"__prefix__"` with the number representing the index the new formset should have in its `id`, `name` and `label` attributes. For example, if it's the second formset on the page its `id` will be `id_form-1-title` (changed from `id_form-__prefix__-title`).
3. In the html for the new formset, also include a hidden `input` element to replace the one creted by django's `ManagementForm` to update the value of `form-TOTAL_FORMS`. Place `hx-swap-oob="true"` on that `input` so that it replaces the old element.

A longer explanation with example code is at: [The right way to dynamically add Django formset instances and POST usign HTMX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757197/the-right-way-to-dynamically-add-django-formset-instances-and-post-usign-htmx/74924295#74924295)

Docs reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 0):

A trick you can use here is that Django allows you to change the formset's `min_num` after it's created, letting you return any form index in a formset. The thing that you want to substitute with htmx is the new form and the management form, so you can create a view returning those:

```py
def new_form(request: HttpRequest, i: int):
    formset = MyFormset()
    formset.min_num = i + 1
    context = {'next': i + 1,
               'form': formset.forms[i],
               'management_form': formset.management_form}
    return render(request, 'myapp/partial/new_form.html', context)
```

where the template looks like

```html
<div class="form">{{ form }}</div>
<div id="new_form">
    {{ management_form.TOTAL_FORMS }}
    <button hx-target="#new_form" hx-get="/new_form/{{ next }}">
        Add Form
    </button>
</div>
```

Notice how the management form is inside the thing htmx replaces.

This approach keeps the benefit of formsets that they are all submitted at once rather than individually.