# How to let the user add as many forms as they want to a ModelForm that saves to the same model in django

Tags: python, django

I have a form to let users make a new poll, it consists of 2 ModelForms one for the Question model and another for the Choice model

a screenshot:

[Make new poll form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzK9y.png)

i want there to be something like a (+) or (add another choice) button where users can add as many choices as they want and then submit it all.

here's the models.py file

```
models.py


from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()




class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    questionText = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    datePublished = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def str(self):
        return self.questionText


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choiceText = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    choiceVotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def str(self):
        return self.choiceText
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Question
from .models import Choice




class NewPollForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        labels = { 
            "questionText":"Poll question"
        }

        fields = ("questionText",)



class NewChoicesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        labels = {
            "choiceText":"Choice"
        }
        fields = ("choiceText",)
```

the view for this form's page you can see it is set for only one choice field right now

```
from .forms import NewPollForm
from .forms import NewChoicesForm


def newpoll(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated == True :
        pass
    else:
        return redirect("users:signup")
    if request.method == "POST":
        qform = NewPollForm(request.POST)
        cform = NewChoicesForm(request.POST)
        if qform.is_valid():
            newpoll = qform.save(commit=False)
            newpoll.user = request.user
            newpoll.datePublished = timezone.now()
            newpoll.save()
            cform.instance.question = newpoll
            cform.save()
            return redirect("polls:details", pollid=newpoll.pk)
        else:
            return render (request, "polls/newpoll.html", {"qform":qform, "cform":cform})
    else:
        qform = NewPollForm()
        cform = NewChoicesForm()
        return render (request, "polls/newpoll.html", {"qform":qform, "cform":cform})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically adding a form to a Django formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset). You will need to use [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). The above linked question shows how to dynamically add more forms to the formset.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat No, not sure it uses javascript isn't there another way?

Comment: And how else would you do things dynamically when you have to do them at the _client side_ without using JavaScript (At least when the client is a browser)?

Comment: That's what i'm asking for, i'm new this is my first app i was looking for an answer using python in the views or maybe the models.py